# ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'REGEXP_INSTR'

Tags: mysql

I'm getting error when try to run the following statement.

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR("test", "e", 1, 1, 0, "m");
```

Output :

```
ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'REGEXP_INSTR'
```

But when only first and second parameters are supplied, the error is gone.

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR("test", "e");
```

Output :

```
+---------------------------+
| REGEXP_INSTR("test", "e") |
+---------------------------+
|                         2 |
+---------------------------+
```

But, in manual says that `REGEXP_INSTR` has 4 optional parameters.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr

Comment: It works [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zTLKczNP)

Comment: @Ergest Basha true and OP tagged mysql, but can reproduce error in mariadb..

Comment: @Usman Nasution please add output from select version()

Comment: @P.Salmon *but can reproduce error in MariaDB*, true, but OP not only tagged MySQL , but linked to MySQL documentation as well. We should wait for the `select version()` , I guess

Comment: In MariaDB this function have 2 parameters only - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_instr/